# Common loggers for all views in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, django-logging

Here is my loggers configuration of settings.py on my Django sever.

```
'loggers': {
        'tutorial.view_test': {
            'handlers': ['logfile','console','mail_admins'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
```

I am able to log the details using the above loggers configurations for views "tutorial.view_test". But if i want to log for all my view in my project with a common loggers. How can i do that.